# Bootstrap Modal Fade does not go away when I hit the X button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a regular install of boostrap 2.3, and my modal's work 100% fine, except when you click on the X on the top right corner of the screen to close, the fade does not go away. If you hit close, or click anywhere else, the modal closes correctly. It is only when you click the X in the header. I am using an image as the link, instead of a button.

---

Here is the code I am using:

```
                <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×x</button>
                        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>One fine body…</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class="sectionisland"><img src="img/courses/personascenario.png"></div></a>
```

The code is copied from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals, you can see the X in the top when you click the button.

Comment: The code you posted is alright. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to call modal manually $('#myModal').modal('hide');